# SQL Server Multiply Without Asterisk (*)

Tags: sql-server

I'm working in an asset management system that allows me to create charts. I'm attempting to get a SQL query to work in it, and apparently they don't want a select all query performed, so they have a condition that prevents the asterisk in the select statement. However, I want to multiply order quantity by the order amount to provide a chart showing how much money is spent per budget.

How can I bypass their stupidity to get that price times quantity value into my query?

```
select budget, price * qty as 'amount spent'
from orderline
```

Comment: Honestly, by telling them they are stupid. The `*` character has *multiple* uses in T-SQL.

Comment: Price / (1/qty)

Comment: Assuming that `qty` is an integer value, @siggemannen, you probably want `1./qty`.

Comment: @thomA even better!

Comment: /* guessing this comment would be a problem */?

Comment: I would honestly love to see the face of the person (fool) who banned the use of `*` have to QC an expression like `(V.Price / (1./V.Qty)) / (1./(1+V.TaxPercent))` because their poor developers couldn't write `V.Price * V.Qty * (1+V.TaxPercent)`

Comment: I mean, they do prevent laziness. As well as a lot of regular code 

Comment: I suppose it's a good thing, at least, that it's not 1991 anymore; if it were you'd be unable to do an ANSI-89 OUTER JOIN (`FROM T1, T2 WHERE T1.ID *= T2.T1ID`).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think to divide by 1 divided by the number! Very much appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I agree this limitation is absurd. If you have control of the schema though, you could create a user-defined scalar function to do it.

```
CREATE FUNCTION MULTIPLY
(
    @param1 AS FLOAT,
    @param2 AS FLOAT
)
RETURNS FLOAT
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN @param1 * @param2
END
```

then:

```
SELECT budget, dbo.MULTIPLY(price,qty) as 'amount spent' FROM orderline
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you have predefined `decimal(18,0)` for both the *input* and *output* that could result in terrible rounding implications. `18.46 * 4.49= 82.8854` but your function would return `72`. Not to mention that when multiplying SQL Server automatically grows the precision (and shrinks the scale if needed), which this won't do.

Comment: Also, you probably can't create the function cause the character is forbidden. Unless one does some creative use of char() calls and dynamic sql

Comment: @ThomA you are right, I edited to change the types to help the rounding problem for prices, but there could still be rounding errors if higher precision is required.